# Constructor problems with inheritance and generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am having a hard time understanding generics with inheritance. The error I am getting is:

```
Stage.java:66: error: constructor Stage in class Stage<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        {
        ^
  required: ArrayList<T>,double,ArrayList<T>
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Stage
```

What I have is a subclass called Stage0 (an inline class of Stage) that inherits from Stage. Stage0 is to have essentially the same functionality bar - Stage0 will @Override a method from its parent class.
Here is from Line 63 of the Stage class (which is the beginning of Stage0)

```
class Stage0 extends Stage<T>
{
    Stage0(ArrayList<T> inQ, double inputTime, ArrayList<T> outQ)
    {
        inputQueue = inQ;
        takesTime = inputTime;
        outputQueue = outQ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStarving(double time)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is the source of my error?

Cheers.

```
public class Stage<T> // equivalent to a 'storage'
{
    private T holdItem;
    private boolean blocked;
    private double takesTime, timeTaken, blockedTime, starveTime;
    private ArrayList<T> inputQueue, outputQueue;

    public Stage(ArrayList<T> inQ, double inputTime, ArrayList<T> outQ)
    {
        inputQueue = inQ;
        takesTime = inputTime;
        outputQueue = outQ;
    }
```

Comment: Please give code of  Stage class.

Comment: @jelleB Stage code has been added. T.J. has solved the problem already. I will mark the question solved as such. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't specified a call to `super` in your `Stage0` constructor code, the compiler inserts it for you, as though you had typed this:

```
Stage0(ArrayList<T> inQ, double inputTime, ArrayList<T> outQ)
{
    super();                       // <======================
    inputQueue = inQ;
    takesTime = inputTime;
    outputQueue = outQ;
}
```

From the error message, it appears that `Stage` has no matching constructor. The error says:

> constructor Stage in class Stage cannot be applied to given types...
>   
>    required: ArrayList,double,ArrayList
>   
>    found: no arguments

That is, you're trying to call `super()` when the best matching constructor it can find is `super(ArrayList<T>,double,ArrayList<T>)`.

The solution is to use `super` explicitly, providing the necessary arguments. In your case, again based on the error message, that would be:

```
Stage0(ArrayList<T> inQ, double inputTime, ArrayList<T> outQ)
{
    super(inQ, inputTime, outQ);   // <======================
    inputQueue = inQ;
    takesTime = inputTime;
    outputQueue = outQ;
}
```

Comment: This solved it! I will mark as solved as soon as the timer is up - Thanks!